# Mount all internal partitions on startup for ALL users

Tags: mount, 20.04, gnome-disk-utility

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it is the first time for me using Linux as a desktop instead of a server. And as such, there are a few pitfalls I keep hitting.

On macOS and Windows 10, I use ownCloud's sync client to move my files between my dedicated server and devices. But on my desktop, I have an entire dedicated HDD to store my ownCloud data. Thus, it needs to be mounted on startup.

If I leave the options to "Session defaults" in the Disks program, nothing happens as I log in. By forcefuly telling it to mount on system start, it does so - but now as `root`, which my merely mortal user can't write to - which I kinda need to do every now and then.

So how can I get all my partitions, on startup, for all users (me) to read/write from/to?

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is the system file that defines mounts, and which mounts must occur at startup. [Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)

Comment: So there is no plain GUI method? I did see that I could specify parameters in the partition settings - I guess those are the fstab settings?

Comment: Plain GUI method: https://superuser.com/questions/346606/is-there-any-gui-tool-to-configure-etc-fstab

Comment: @user535733Turns out pySDM is not available in 20.04. I took a look at how the file browser mounts disks; it mounts them with `uid=$UID`. So since I am the only user on this maschine anyway, this might be a feasable "workaround"... Feels quite hack-y though. I thought `rw` or just using `defaults` would do the trick - but it didn't. Unfortunate, really. :/